# Error while using DynamoDB AWS SDK [No Mapping for Hash Key] because of naming convention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamo-local

While using AWS JAva SDK, for defining DynamoDBHashKey we @DynamoDBHashKey annotation.

**Strangely if i use annotation as below**

```
@DynamoDBHashKey 
String Abc
```

instead of

```
@DynamoDBHashKey 
String abc
```

> this gives me an error,
>   no mapping for HASH key
>       [junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.hashKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:119)
>       [junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel$Builder.build(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:449)
>       [junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$StandardTableFactory.getTable(StandardModelFactories.java:104)
>       [junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.getTableModel(DynamoDBMapper.java:393)
>       [junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:2148)
>       [junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:319)

I am unable to understand why does variable naming convention plays a role in failure Any Idea?

Comment: If the solution below works for you please accept and up vote. You might consider filing an issue on the AWS SDK for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Introspection magic does not appear to be working in this case. [Force the attribute name](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBHashKey.java#L40) with the parameter `attributeName`.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="Books")
public static class Book {
    private String Abc;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="Abc")
    public int getAbc() {
        return Abc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forget to add this, i tried the same in infact i did mention attributenae explicictly still faced the same issue